# Convert Binary BIT to an Index Number for Array - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, bit-manipulation

I need a way of determining or mapping a Binary BIT when set to an Index number for an `array` in Swift.

For example, I have have a `uInt64` that has a BIT set `0b0010 0000 0000 ...`, I would like to translate it in terms of an Index number for an `array` that ranges  from `0` to `39`.

So the `msb` would be `0` and the `lsb` would be `39`

Also, I need a way of identifying the most recent bit that has been switched.

For example, say the first is: `0b0010 0000 0000 ....` and the second is `0x0010 0010 0000 ....` until the integer is at its highest value i.e. `0xFFFFFFFF..`

**UPDATE**:

After much helpful feedback, I have another problem which is identifying as to whether a variable has changed in Swift:

```
var changedValue: UInt64? {
                        willSet(newValue : UInt64) {
                            guard let oldValue = value, new = newValue else { return }
                            if oldValue != new { oldValue ^ newValue }
                            }
                        }
```

It doesn't work with UInt64

Comment: You can use `didSet` to see if a variable has been set and compare current value to `oldValue`.  Note, in your code `{ oldValue ^ newValue }` computes a value but doesn't store it anywhere.

Comment: Now you mix two completely different problem in one question  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XOR operator can be used to identify which bits have changed:

```
let oldValue: UInt64 = 0b0010_0000_0000
let newValue: UInt64 = 0b0010_0010_0000

let diff = oldValue ^ newValue
```

and the [`ffsll()`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/3/FFS/) ("find first set, long long") function computes the position of the least significant bit which is *set* in the difference:

```
let bitpos = Int(ffsll(Int64(bitPattern: diff)))
print(bitpos) // 6
```

If a change in the least significant bit corresponds to index 39
in your array then compute

```
let index = 40 - bitpos
```

Comment: Nice use of `ffsll`.  Why reinvent the wheel?  It didn't work for Swift on Linux though.

Comment: @vacawama: It should be available on Linux, but perhaps not imported to Swift (cannot test it currently). – The nice thing is that it translates to compiler intrinsics where available: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#Tool_and_library_support .

Comment: @vacawama: `import Glibc ; print(ffs(4))` works on https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl, but not the long/long long variants.

Answer (score 1):

One basic approach would be to right shift the number until it becomes zero, keeping track of how many times it takes to do that:

```
func maskToIndex(_ mask: UInt64) -> Int {
    var mask = mask
    var result = 40

    repeat {
        mask >>= 1
        result -= 1
    } while mask != 0

    return result
}

print(maskToIndex(0x0000000001))  // 39
print(maskToIndex(0x0000000002))  // 38
print(maskToIndex(0x0000000004))  // 37

print(maskToIndex(0x8000000000))  // 0
print(maskToIndex(0x4000000000))  // 1
print(maskToIndex(0x2000000000))  // 2
```

---

To identify the most recent bit switched on, apply exclusive-OR to the previous and current values to isolate the new bit:

```
let previous = 0b100
let current = 0b110
let newbit = previous ^ current  // newbit = 2 = 0b010
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I am after, but what mast should I pass in?  Should I pass it `0x8000000000`?

Comment: I've just thought, I am going to have BITS switched at different points within the `uInt64` variable, so what happens when I give the function `0b0001 1100 0010 0000 0000`.  Really it needs to identify as to which the NEW BIT which has just been switched.  Would this be a simple case of BIT masking with `&` etc.?

Comment: @user1574598: Please edit and clarify your question. What "new bit" are you talking about? What is the input data, and what the expected output?

Comment: Apply exclusive-OR to your two numbers to isolate the single bit.  `let old = 0b100; let new = 0b110; let bit = old ^ new`.

Comment: Ok, I'm struggling to be able to store an OLD value and update a NEW value - I seem to be in a logical pickle where I am updating the OLD with the NEW and both being equal to each other!